# Как отсортировать словарь по последовательности из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, dict

Есть условный словарь:

```
inp = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
```

Список в определенной последовательности:

```
sorted_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

На выход хочу получить словарь, отсортированный по sorted_list:

```
out = {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
```

Вопрос. Как?

Comment: Словарь - это неупорядоченная структура. К нему в принципе не применимо понятие "отсортированный".

Comment: Вы можете привести словарь к другой, упорядоченной структуре (кортеж, список) и работать с ней.

Comment: Смотря какая задача на самом деле: например, если вам нужно вывести данные  из словаря в порядке ключей из списка, для этого не нужно "сортировать" словарь, нужно просто циклом пройтись по списку и получать значений из словаря по ключам из списка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже сказали в комментариях:

> Словарь - это неупорядоченная структура.

Но если вам нужно лишь вывести в таком порядке, то можно так:

```
inp = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
sorted_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for key in sorted_list:
    print(f'{key}: {inp.get(key)}')
```

Вот так можно "преобразовать" словарь в список кортежей:

```
inp = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
sorted_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

inp_list = [(key, inp.get(key)) for key in sorted_list]
```

Можно использовать `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
inp = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
sorted_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

ord_dict = OrderedDict()
for key in sorted_list:
    ord_dict[key] = inp.get(key)
```

Поджатый метод с использованием `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
inp = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}
sorted_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ord_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(inp.items(), key=lambda x: sorted_list.index(x[0])))
```